# Would Amazon AWS Services be a good alternative to my current hosting provider?

Tags: server, server-load, amazon, web-services

My WP sites keep crashing my server because I have huge amounts of load in a short amount of time.  The server has to be rebooted every few minutes.  We have tried everything but nothing seems to work...would Amazon AWS Services be a good alternative?  If so, which AWS services would work best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS is good, but a bit hard to understand if you've never set up a server. You should take a look at http://rackspace.com for their cloud server package. It's about $25 USD/month for a decent server. They also have a control panel for load balancing setup. I've hosted a bunch of WP sites on my cloud servers there with no issues. Support is fantastic.

Comment: They just quoted me $304 monthly for the managed one.  Do you manage the server yourself?

Comment: I manage my own server. http://misternifty.com/internet/servers/build-your-own-server-tutorial/  Here's a simple way to start. I wrote this a while ago...might be helpful for you.

Comment: Awesome!  I will do this and keep you posted.  Thank you soooo much.

Comment: One more question.  I know I need about 4GB RAM, is there a specific plan I should select at Rackspace?

Comment: The way Rackspace cloud works is you can build whatever size of server you need, and then add more memory as you go. You can resize the server on the fly if you need more. They also have a load balancer where you can link multiple servers.

Comment: That takes me to my next question.  If I need multiple IPs, is it best to set up each IP in a different server?  I have approximately 200 WP sites

Comment: You can create virtual hosts that house multiple domains. I currently have about 15 WP installs on one server. I would group my low-traffic sites together on a server. If you have a beefy site with lots of concurrent connections, put it on it's own IP. Just my two cents. :)

Comment: Can you make the transfer for me?  How much do you charge?  How can I reach you directly for details?

Comment: Sorry mate, I work full time and I don't freelance. I offer knowledge assistance here in my free time. You can try to find someone on http://jobs.wordpress.net/